# Loop over a list of dataframes and change column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frames in which some data frames  are abit messed up with column names and my intention is to loop over the list of data frame columns, identify those data frames where the columns are messed up then be able to delete the column names and replace the first row to be column names, this is my data frames sample

```
dput(df)
structure(list(v1 = c("Silva", "Brandon", "Mango"),
               v2 = c("James","Jane", "Egg")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))

dput(df2)
structure(list(X2 = c("v1", "Brandon", "Mango"),
               X..X1 = c("v2","Jane", "Egg")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

Now this is the example of my dataframes where we have a dataframe in which the column names in df2 are appearing as rows, I need to loop through see which dataframes have  messed up column names like df2 then delete the column names and replace with first row this is what I tried

```
dflist <- list(df,df2)
remNames <- c("X2", "X..x1")
dflist <- c()
for (i in 1:length(dflist)) {

  if(dflist[[i]][names(dflist[[i]])] == remNames){

    colnames(dflist[[i]]) <- dflist[[i]][1,]
    dflist[[i]] = dflist[[i]][-1, ]

  }

}
```

This doesn't work, what am I missing out, my EXPECTED OUTPUT is the list of data frames to have same column names which are supposed to be **V1** and **V2**

Comment: Remove `dflist<-c()` as now `dflist` will be empty, replace `if(dflist[[i]][names(dflist[[i]])] == remNames)` with `if(any(names(dflist[[i]]) == remNames))`, to see what is going on inside the for loop; define i=1 then run the body in the R console as usual.

Comment: @A. Suliman I dont get it, could you reproduce the code, I have tried fixing that but I get errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dflist <- list(df,df2)
for (i in 1:length(dflist)) {

if(any(names(dflist[[i]]) == remNames)){
    colnames(dflist[[i]]) <- dflist[[i]][1,]
    dflist[[i]] = dflist[[i]][-1, ]
  }

}
```

`dflist[[i]][names(dflist[[i]])] == remNames` will check the enitre dataframe, hence `if` will return FALSE and nothing happend, consider the following example when `i=2`

```
> i=2
> dflist[[i]][names(dflist[[i]])] == remNames
        X2 X..X1
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE
```

A better solution is to use `grepl` to see if the column names contain a `..` or `X`, so the if becomes

```
if(any(grepl('\\.\\.|X',names(dflist[[i]])))){...}
```